# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, newrelic

I've got the script below

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='example.com']").addEventListener('click',function (e) {
            newrelic.addPageAction('Doc');

        })
    });
```

I am trying to capture count of hits whenever the user opens the document enclosed within anchor tag with href present but no ID property. The document opens in another window. Is the above correct way to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of elements, so you should iterate over it ad add the event listener

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='example.com']")].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
            newrelic.addPageAction('Doc');
    }))
});
```

Comment: How many browsers support `[...document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='example.com']")]`? Where can i find documentation about it?
And what different if you will use `document.querySelectorAll("a").firEach()` vs `[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].forEach()`

You can try on browser `document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(e=>{console.log(e)})` and `[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].forEach(e=>{console.log(e)})` and will get the same result

I know that [..] is Array but without is HTMLCollection but both of it working good with `.forEach() ` or im wrong?

Comment: @Greg-- you can check JS and CSS support here https://caniuse.com/ , however i don't think that `HTMLCollection.forEach` si such a widely supported method, i can't find it in MDN

Comment: Thank you! Sorry my misstake, querySelectorAll return NodeList not HTMLCollection, so you can check it in [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach) but how could i check [..] in can i  use? Its something like Array.from()? Or what? Where did you find documentation about [..]

Comment: @Greg-- well it's the spread operator, search it in caniuse and you should find it, however by the looks of things, `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='example.com']")).foreach( ... )` should also work

Comment: So i dini't find it ([..toarray] in MDN

Comment: @Greg-- because are 2 things, one is `[ ]` that is the array notation, and the second is `...` that is the spread operator

Comment: @Berto99: Because it is a `NodeList` and not a `HTMLCollection`. [Support of NodeList and forEach on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Unless you support IE, you can drop the spread.

Comment: @Lain yep, sorry, don't even thought about checking ahah

Comment: @Berto99 this one? [spread in array?](https://caniuse.com/#search=Spread%20in%20array%20literals)

Comment: About NodeList - my misstake i write it on top.

Comment: @Greg-- all the use of the spread operator is equally supported https://caniuse.com/#search=Spread%20operator so i suppose it doesn't really matter in which case we are, but in my opinion we are looking at the case that you have linked, yes

Comment: Thank you! Thats what i want to find (can i use or not)!

Answer (score 4):

You need to go through each element returned by querySelectorAll()

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[href='example.com']").forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click',function (e) {
            newrelic.addPageAction('Doc');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

document.querySelectorAll() is returns a NodeList so you can't add an eventListener. You can try to visit all elements with for loop and add eventListener for each one.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
     var x = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='example.com']");
     for(i=0;i<x.length; i++){
         x[i].addEventListener('click',function (e) {
                newrelic.addPageAction('Doc');
    
            })
        });
```

Comment: It returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not an `Array`.