# Why is the event listener added only to the first element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, hoisting

So, after a button is clicked, there is this loop which goes through the array and creates a div containing data from each array element. Now, after the divs are injected into DOM, I add an event listener to them, but only the firstly added element responds. :/ The others are dead. Any tips?

```js
btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let output = "";
    for(let x of array){
        output += `<div class="listItem" data-id="${x.id}">
            <ul>
                <li>Name: ${x.name}</li>
                <li>Price: ${x.price}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>`;
    }

    leftList.innerHTML = output;

    document.querySelector(".listItem").addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: _“Any tips?”_ - go read up on what `querySelector` actually does …? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector: _“[…] returns the **first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector”_

Comment: You can use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. For more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks, guys! I looped through the elements and added a listener to each.

Answer (score 0):

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Since, `document.querySelector(".listItem")` is only selecting the first element that matches the specified selector, the event listener is applied only to the first element.

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Try using `document.querySelectorAll(".listItem")` and loop through this to add event listeners to all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to best answer for: [Getting error Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633414/getting-error-uncaught-typeerror-document-queryselectorall-addeventlistene), which includes example of how to use forEach() for adding listener to each listItem in class returned by querySelectorAll.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34497011)

Answer (score 0):

You could register an eventListener/handler to each item or you could do it the more efficient way by registering a common ancestor tag to an event (this is called [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)). Doing so would require that you'd only have addEventListener/event property once. All descendant tags of that single ancestor tag pre-existing or added dynamically added at a later time can be delegated to the registered event.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
let data1 = [{id: "x325", name: "CCTV Hub",  price: 139.99}, {id: "x963", name: "Motion Detector", price: 45.99}, {id: "x117", name: "Flood Light",  price: 89.99}, {id: "x581", name: "Alarm System", price: 325.99}];

let data2 = [{id: "x369", name: "Night Vision Goggles",  price: 349.99}, {id: "x020", name: "Metal Detector", price: 149.99}, {id: "x823", name: "Binoculars",  price: 279.99}];

// Reference menu.list
const list = document.querySelector(".list");

/**
 * Register button.btn to the "click" event.
 * The event handler is an anonymous function which allows us to
 * call another function that paasses a parameter other than 
 * the Event Object.
 * Note: menu.list is the ancestor tag registered to the "click"
 * event only once. Any tag pre-existing or dynamically added
 * within menu.list can be delegated to the "click" event.
 */
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  createList(data1);
  this.disabled = true; // Avoid double clicking
  list.addEventListener("click", getID);
});

/**
 * Register buttoon.add to the "click" event.
 * This eventListener is simular to it's predecessor but it 
 * doesn't register menu.list to the "click" event since it 
 * already is.
 */
document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  createList(data2); // Avoid double clicking
  this.disabled = true;
});

/**
 * Creates an array of strings from an array of objects.
 * The array is then converted into a single string.
 * Then that string is rendered as HTML inside of menu.list.
 */
function createList(objArr) {
  const items = objArr.map(obj => {
    return `<li data-id="${obj.id}">
              <ul>
                <li>Name: ${obj.name}</li>
                <li>Price: ${obj.price}</li>
              </ul>
            </li>`;
  }).join('');

  list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", items);
}

/**
 * This named function is an event handler.
 * clicked is the tag the user actually clicked.
 * If the user clicked a tag that has an ancestor tag with a 
 * [data-id] attribute, log that [data-id] value.
 */
function getID(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;
  if (clicked.closest("[data-id]")) {
    console.log(clicked.closest("[data-id]").dataset.id);
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2.25ch/1.25 "Segoe UI"
}

menu,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Start List</button>
<button class="add">Add New List</button>
<menu class="list"></menu>
```