# When I press the button it gives me one result and not all the Map results I have. I only get value 1

Tags: javascript

I need help.

There's something in the code that's not working properly for me.

When I press a button it pulls me value of value of one product and every other button just does not pull their figure.

```
const itemadd = document.querySelectorAll('.item-this');
let currentAccount;
let proteinValue;

const foods = new Map([
    ['קוטג',23],
    ['ביצה',11],
    ['יוגורט Pro',20],
    ['טונה',23]
]);


foods.forEach(function (value, index, arr) {
  const html = `<li class="">
      <strong>${index}</strong> כמות חלבון ${(proteinValue =
    value)}</li><button class="btn btn-primary item-this">הוסף</button><hr>`;
  items.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
});
const itemadd = document.querySelectorAll('.item-this');
for (let i = 0; i < itemadd.length; i++)
  itemadd[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(proteinValue);
  });
```

When I press the button it only records the figure of ['tuna', 23]
Intention 23 and all the other entries do not print them for me that I press the button

Comment: instead of ID, use class to select element and use 'this' to get the value. ID should be unique in the document. Here 'add' is not unique. So instead use class.

Comment: When I try to select this class it does not work.
Just id I do not know why. @FarhanHaque

Comment: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - 
The ID of the element to locate. **The ID is case-sensitive string which is unique within the document; only one element may have any given ID.**

Comment: I changed it to class
queryselctor.
Only one button works for me.
Everything else does not work. @crashmstr

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) - An Element object representing the **first element in the document that matches** the specified set of CSS selectors, or null is returned if there are no matches.

**If you need a list of all elements matching the specified selectors, you should use querySelectorAll() instead.**

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function.
this is my error when i use querySelectorAll()

Comment: See [Getting error Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(…).addEventListener is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633414/getting-error-uncaught-typeerror-document-queryselectorall-addeventlistene).

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` would return an *array* and for each of those items in the array, you would need to add an event listener.

Comment: I tried.
I did querySelectorAll.
I tried to export it by for loop.
It did not work.  @crashmstr

Comment: If you query the document for something before you put that something into the document, are you expecting to find those items that are not there yet?

Comment: I fixed it.
All buttons work but I get the same result in all buttons Why?
I get 23. @crashmstr

Comment: 1) questions are not intended to change as you fix things. *Ask a new question instead once you get an answer that works for that problem* 2) you have a second loop and the variable `proteinValue` at that point has only one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach event handler to the button directly and pass the corresponding value.

```
let currentAccount={};
let proteinValue;

const foods = new Map([
    ['קוטג',23],
    ['ביצה',11],
    ['יוגורט Pro',20],
    ['טונה',23]
]);


foods.forEach(function(value,index,arr){

const html = `<li class=""> <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="test(${value})" data-protein="${value}">הוסף</button>
<strong>${index}</strong> כמות חלבון ${proteinValue = value}</li><hr>`
items.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

})

function test(val){
    console.log(val);
}
```

or with eventListener, you can use data attribute.

```
let currentAccount={};
let proteinValue;

const foods = new Map([
    ['קוטג',23],
    ['ביצה',11],
    ['יוגורט Pro',20],
    ['טונה',23]
]);


foods.forEach(function(value,index,arr){

const html = `<li class=""> <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary" data-protein="${value}">הוסף</button>
<strong>${index}</strong> כמות חלבון ${proteinValue = value}</li><hr>`
items.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);

})

document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary').forEach((ele) => {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-protein'))
    })
})
```

Comment: I get zero from insertAdjacentHTMl.

The code does not work. @Farhan Haque

Comment: check now. Instead of items.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html), I did a mistake there. @DanielBarda
'items' is whatever DOM node you want the html to insert into.

Comment: working :) tnxx
But I have to.
Let's have it on addEventListener Because of the system
 @Farhan Haque

Comment: Glad it helped. You can mark the answer as accepted so that it help others.